# How to load a part of application before loading rest of the application in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, optimization, usability

I could not think of a better title, Please suggest one.

I am planning to work on a large web application. It will take time to load the full application before application starts functioning.

Suppose its something like asana.com. If you have a link to the task and you open the link. It loads the application first and then shows the detail of the task. 
*Note: I have added another example in update 2*

I want to do just the opposite. Suppose if I try to open the link directly. It should show me the tasks details first and then load the whole application in background.

What development strategy should I follow to implement such feature. Will angular be good for this? I have worked with angular for small projects and am capable of think in angular :)
I just wanted to be pointed in right direction.

**Update 1:**
I am using Apache2 PHP5 in backing as ReST API. I am thinking to change to GoLang http server. But that does not matter in this context :)

**Update 2:**
I have not yet started working on the application, but I know that its size is going to be big and its going to take time to load the application. This will be a javascript application, all the communication to web will be done mostly by API. APIs will be fast and it wont be slowing down the application. My main concern is the javascript library and the approach to the issue that I want to display the content of the page before the application is loaded and load the application in background. 
As second example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/a-journey-through-middle/gjgkjeheegjnnmheaflhdocglkiegoni?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon 
If you open this link in chrome, it will load the application and then load the specific content in a popup. I want to load the content of the popup first and then load the application in background. How should I write my application to achieve that.

Comment: What's your build process? What's on the backend? Also, your link is broken.

Comment: Sorry, "link" is just a text, its not an actual link, Let me edit the question accordingly.

Comment: So, do you have any sort of build process? Do you have something to compile your JS into a single file? How many Angular modules does your app have? When you say "it takes time to load the full application" are you serving from your local machine or from a server? It would be very helpful if you provided a link. There are a lot of factors that could be making your app load slowly. It's going to be pretty hard to get help without a lot more details.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan I have not yet started working on the application, I am just planning it ahead. These are some of the things I want to clarify before I jump into coding.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (and I say this as I start to do similar vs. having proven it successful) would be to make some level of framework fairly static so that users get an almost instant response to the site loaded and then start the angular app with something like this

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("container"), ["app"])

Ref for the api - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap
Ref for a demonstration of this - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-bootstrap-app-init

My expectation then is that you will be able to

1. Load your static elements quickly (which will just have placeholders for your content/material)
2. Access the data you want in the order you want to get it to present on the screen
3. Release any other part of the app you need to chrome it up/decorate or populate side items.

Comment: As an added comment - 
To avoid "blinking" you can ng-bind vs. using {{}} syntax (**careful as considerations and comments I've seen are optimized assuming a big wrapper starting the app all at once)
http://branchandbound.net/blog/web/2013/08/some-angularjs-pitfalls/

Finally for a manageable page with far too many elements you might be interested in this blog & associated conversation.
http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/

Hope that helps if this is still a valid question.